# Why custom spinner not hiding it's dropdown after selecting an item in android?

Tags: android

I have created a spinner. In which, i get spinner item from JSON file.

Here, is Adapter.java

```
package adapter;


import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.angelnx.cricvilla.cricvilla.R;

import java.util.List;


public class ScheduleSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private Context context;
    private List<String> arr_data;
    public ScheduleSpinnerAdapter(Context context,int resource,List<String> arr_data){
        super(context,resource,arr_data);
        this.context=context;
        this.arr_data=arr_data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row,parent,false);

        TextView txtname=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_value);
        txtname.setText(this.arr_data.get(position));

//        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                Toast.makeText(context, "Selected"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            }
//        });
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row,parent,false);

        TextView txtname=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_value);
        txtname.setText(this.arr_data.get(position));

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Selected" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Here is my spinner_row.xml which inflate in adapter's both method's.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinner_value"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="what"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center|start"
        android:textColor="@color/txtColor"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here, is set the values to adapter

```
ArrayAdapter adapter=new ScheduleSpinnerAdapter(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Problem is after selecting an item form drowpdown. Drowpdown is not hide in my case.

Please help me to solve out this problem.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213278/custom-spinner-not-hiding-the-dropdown-menu-after-selection) ,might help u to hide drop down

Answer (score 3):

Calling `onDetachedFromWindow()` will hide the Spinner dropdown.

```
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) context.findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
            if (spinner != null) {
                try {
                    Method method = Spinner.class.getDeclaredMethod("onDetachedFromWindow");
                    method.setAccessible(true);
                    method.invoke(spinner);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```